# jQuery .each() not recognising all elements.

Tags: jquery, html, each

So I have my grid based layout:

```
<div id="gridrow" class="clear">
<div id="gridsection" class="float-left">
    <div id="gridwrap">
        <div id="gridimage" class="clear"></div>
        <div id="gridtitle" class="clear">Title</div>
        <div id="gridinfo" class="clear">Info</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="gridsection" class="float-right">
    <div id="gridwrap">
        <div id="gridimage" class="clear"></div>
        <div id="gridtitle" class="clear">Title</div>
        <div id="gridinfo" class="clear">Info</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="gridsection" class="gridmiddle">
    <div id="gridwrap">
        <div id="gridimage" class="clear"></div>
        <div id="gridtitle" class="clear">Title</div>
        <div id="gridinfo" class="clear">Info</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I then have this jQuery script:

```
$("#gridtitle").each(function(index){
    $("#gridtitle:eq("+index+")").click(function (){
        $("#gridimage:eq("+index+"), #gridinfo:eq("+index+")").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

I thought this would work (made logical sense) however, only the first grid element will work, any tips?

For more information please feel free to ask,

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different elements must have differend IDs.

If two or more elements have the same ID, only first is used.

Comment: Exactly, he should use another class instead: `<div class="clear gridimage"></div>`

Answer (score 1):

ID's are unique , you can only use one for each object. You might use classed instead, and change the selectors :

```
$(".gridtitle").each(function(index){
    $(".gridtitle:eq("+index+")").click(function (){
        $(".gridimage:eq("+index+"),.gridinfo:eq("+index+")").slideToggle();
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `gridtitle` is an `id`. You should instead change it to be a `class` and select it like this:

```
$(".gridtitle").each(function() { ... });
```